# Binding button to element inside ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, unique, bind

I'm trying to bind a button inside `ng-repeat` to that unique element for the button within the same repeat, pretty hard to word for me so I'll give a code snippet.

```
<li ng-repeat="thing in listOfThings track by $index">
  <div ng-model="text"> text < /div>
  <button ng-click="highlightText()" />
</ li>
```

Although not exact, that's the idea. The problem is that when I click the button, it will highlight all the texts inside the `listOfThings`. 
 
Note: assume that the text is given a ng-class that highlights when a boolean is true, and not highlighted when it's false, toggled by the button.

Any idea how to "bind" that button to only that one text so it doesn't highlight everything else?

I've tried to google for it, it might be a duplicate question but not sure how to search for something this specific so please link the answer if it's a duplicate.

Comment: add the code of `highlightText` function. since ng-repeat create new nested non-isolated scope it could be issue there, or you would get it worked

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your example correctly, your `ng-class` is going to apply the class to all items inside of your repeat based on the click event.

You need to track the button selection individually, by each element in the list. Something like:

HTML:

```
<li data-ng-repeat="thing in listOfThings track by $index">
  <div data-ng-model="text" data-ng-class="{ 'highlighted': thing.Selected  }"> < /div>
  <button data-ng-click="highlightText(thing)" />
</li>
```

JS:

```
$scope.highlightText = function(thing){
    thing.Selected = true;
}
```

CSS:

```
.highlighted{
   background-color: yellow;
}
```

**EDIT**: Good suggestion made by [skyboyer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2071697/skyboyer), this could be made cleaner by moving the highlighted function and not tracking the flag on the `thing` variable.

HTML:

```
<li data-ng-repeat="thing in listOfThings track by $index">
  <div data-ng-model="text" data-ng-class="{ 'highlighted': selected  }"> < /div>
  <button data-ng-click="selected = true" />
</li>
```

Comment: hello P. Best! Welcome to SO. I want to note that since ng-repeat creates new scope(non-isolated) it's possible to skip mutating `thing`. That is you may just use `ng-class="{highlighted: selected}"` with `... ng-click="selected = true" `